# Conectar a um servidor via ssh

Tags: terminal, ssh, mac

Preciso conectar a um servidor via ssh pelo terminal. Porém esse servidor possui uma key. Eu tenho essa key no meu computador, gostaria de saber como faço para acessar o servidor com essa key via ssh pelo terminal do mac.

Answer (score 0):

1. Vá até Finder > Applications > Utilities > Terminal.
2. Caminhe até o diretório da que está sua chave
3. Execute `chmod 600 minha_chave.key` (atenção à extensão do arquivo)
4. Execute `ssh -i minha_chave.key usuario@ipdoservidor`
5. Quando aparecer a mensagem para confirmar, aperte `Enter`